# DMS - Chen notation vs. [min, max] notation

Tags: database-design, entity, rdbms

I am currently taking a Database Management System course, and in that course learning about chen and [min, max] notation.
I have trouble understanding why this figure is correct;
[Chen vs [min,max]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLBcb.png)

So one E_1 can have multiple E_2 if reading the chen notation, however in my head the [min,max] notation is currently saying one E_2 can have multiple E_1.

Anyone care to explain?

Comment: I think you are misreading the Chen notation.

Comment: @WalterMitty How would you read it?

Comment: My mistake.  I agree with the way OP reads Chen.  Sorry.

Comment: Please put text into your question for whatever can be put as text into your question. Like, that entire diagram. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted.

Comment: What reference were you told you use? What does it say? What did googling 'Chen notation vs. [min, max] notation' or that plus 'stackoverflow' tell you?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume we have two entities, *PROFESSOR* and *STUDENT*, with (1:N) cardinality and the relationship between them is *SUPERVISES*. In the ER diagram,  both entities are connected to the relationship via a single line.

According to [Fundamentals of database systems](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Elmasri-Fundamentals-of-Database-Systems-7th-Edition/PGM189052.html):

> In ER diagrams, total participation (or existence dependency) is displayed as a double line connecting the participating entity type to the relationship, whereas partial participation is represented by a single line.

Here we have a single line connecting the entity to the relationship, this means that the participation of the entity in the relationship is **Partial participation**.

From (1:N) cardinality, we know that one professor can supervise many students. And from the single line, we know that one professor may supervise no students at all.

Similarly, one student can be supervised by one professor or no professors.

This can be converted easily to (min, max) notation because you know that one professor can supervise many or no students so the minimum number of students is 0 and no maximum limit so, (*) is used (the letter **n** can be used instead of the asterisk). On the other side, one student can be supervised by no professors or exactly one professor so, the minimum number of professors is 0 and the maximum is 1.