# ERD relationship cardinality - Is it better with reverse placement of symbols?

Tags: database, erd, cardinality, entity-relationship

Contrary to traditional convention, could it be better to draw relationship cardinalities attached to the table having the relationships rather than the tables the relationships are with? In other words let the symbols show the nature of the *following* relationship line, rather than explaining the relationship line *already followed*.

I am making an entity relationship diagram for some tables in an SQL database. The use case for the ERD is when creating a new entry to a table in the database. The goal is to make it easy to understand which other tables the entry is depending on, thus requiring entries too.

The traditional convention is to draw lines from a table to related tables, and then where the lines' are connected to the other tables we draw the relationship cardinality symbols. So if an entry in Table R necessarily must have exactly one related entry in Table C it could look as follows: (Simplified diagram.)

[image: Traditional diagram]

To find which other tables a table is dependent on, it is necessary to follow every connection to a related table to determine required dependency. This can become cumbersome when a database has many tables.

Is it possible then to make an ERD where it is easier to locate dependencies? As stated in the question up top, the most logical solution seems to be to clearly indicate for the reader that the traditional convention for symbol placements have been reversed, and then let the relationship cardinality symbols show the nature of the relationship following the symbols. So if an entry in Table R necessarily must have exactly one related entry in Table C the more readable indication could look as follows:

[image: Reversed diagram]

Disregarding the fact that most people are used to the traditional variant, are there any other benefits to the traditional one when compared to the reversed one I propose directly above? I asked a professor once if my suggestion wasn't better because it allows for easily determining whether or not more tables were required for an entry, and in general allows a more intuitive reading, but he was not able to argue anything beyond what people currently are used to, and tradition is not always worthwhile.

Are there any other alternatives than the ones I have shown above that works better for my goal when having very many tables in the diagram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) you will find a very interesting diagram comparing the way to represent cardinality in 6 different notations.   There is only one which shows cardinality in the reverse way like you'd want it:  it's the "ISO (min,max)" notation (see also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45651792/3723423)).  If you want to use it, stick to the corresponding notation.

Do not reverse the use of [Everest's crowfoot](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/291448084_BASIC_DATA_STRUCTURE_MODELS_EXPLAINED_WITH_A_COMMON_EXAMPLE) notation. You'd end-up being the only one understanding yourself,  and maybe not even everyday if you have to switch between your practice and the common practice very often.  So an advice:  accept the current notations as they are:  they have proven themselves in millions of projects around the globe.

If most notations take the cardinality on side of the target, and if the only notation that put on the reverse side is almost dead (despite the support of international standardization), there must be advantages and reasons that explain this situation. One of the reason is probably that you much more often ask yourself,  what is this entity/class related with (promoting the target consideration) rather than looking for dependencies (where the source view could have some benefits).

### Edit:

I have looked up in my software-paleontology books, and have found a notation that uses your logic with a similar rationale.

It was part of [MERISE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merise), a development methodology that was very popular in France in the 80s and 90s.  It used a variant of the ERD notation, which was called MCD (Conceptual Data Model).  It was later popularized by the [PowerDesigner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerDesigner) tool.  It uses the min max notation without parenthesis,  but uses a distinct way to represent relations:

[image]

Note that the relation symbol can be compressed into a small circle and the connection lines can be annotated. (More explanation, [here](https://merise.developpez.com/faq/?page=MCD#Comment-traduire-un-MCD-en-un-diagramme-de-classe-UML), but unfortunately only in French - and UML seems to have killed that notation).

Comment: I found a line at the bottom of the german page on min-max notation illuminating:

`The (min,max) notation is considered counter-intuitive to Chen in terms of (max) cardinality, because the (min,max) notation counts relationships. Chen, MC and multiplicities count entities!`

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-Max-Notation

I think it would have made more sense for a database ERD to use the the min-max notation, but the common belief seems to be that because something has become standard there has to be a good reason, even though nobody provides actual arguments for the convention.

Comment: However, when using crow's foot it makes more sense to show there can be several entities connected. The many-symbol better represents that there can be several entities than it represents that several relations can be had from one entity. Since crow's foot only requires symbols, compared to the more cumbersome min-max notation, I suspect that is the reason why it has gained more popularity.

Comment: @Sonlun Thanks for this interesting source and arguments.  I fear that this wikipedia article might poorly sourced on one side,  and partial when comparing expressivity.  About the reason, I will safely reiterate my argument. I can, because at the beginning of my career, min-max was still in and I was a proponent, but I quickly changed my mind. It would be too lengthy to develop here (but main hypotheses is in the last para).

Comment: @Sonlun I can confirm that the more symbolic crowfoot was an important factor in my change of perception about mimax, partly because the symbols allowed to reduce confusion between competing notations. I felt it to be more inutuitive as well. But this is a personal opinion and not a valid argument. Now notations are like human languages: the drive that leads to their evolution is not always apparent, but there are always (several) reasons.  Why is latin or saxon not spoken anymore and why do mathematicians not use roman litterals in their formulas ;-)

Comment: I see. I added an answer I have found sufficient to explain what to consider, in case it's helpful for anyone.

Comment: @Sonlun yes it is a good idea.  Meanwhile,  I digged a little bit further and added an edit for the record.

Comment: That is an interesting find. It would be helpful to learn why "entity cardinality" has become more popular than "relationship cardinality", but I haven't found anything explaining it.

Comment: @Sonlun I think the main reason is that in the ER model, people focus on the entities, because they will be mapped to  tables in the implementation and table-based reasoning dominates db design. Association often appear as additional columns in a table (with the exception of many-to-many as well as association entities). This explains why the entity focus won in the end.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the crow's foot notation lends itself better to showing the possible number of entities in a table there can be on each side of a relation.

In practice it is thus not advisable to reverse the placement of the symbols, especially because it would conflict with the standards most people are familiar with.

An argument could be made that the min-max notation could be fitting for a database ERD if the goal is to make it easy to see which other tables you also need to update when adding a new element to some table. The min-max notation is showing the amount of possible relations an entity in a table can have, while notations like crow's foot notation shows how many entities there could possibly be on either end of a relation. (I suggest reading a translation of https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-Max-Notation )

However, the simplicity of the crow's foot notation symbols could be argued to make information quicker to absorb at a glance. It also requires less space, thus possibly clutter the ERD less. These benefits might outshine the benefits of the min-max notation. Crow's foot notation's biggest drawback is only a problem for very complex ERDs where it can be difficult to follow the relationship lines to determine whether an entity is required in another table too.